# SSRS Separate Table for each grouping

Tags: layout, reporting-services

I have a simple SSRS report which has one group and details.  The grouping is by employee and the details are performance data on each.  After tedious calculation, it just comes down to

```
select * from table
```

and I have SSRS do the grouping on the employee column.  There are several tasks for each employee, so that is why the grouping in the first place.

My problem is, the user would like to be able to distribute these stats to the employees, and it would be easier if there were some white space between these groups (between each employee).

I've tried adding a blank row inside or outside the group, but I can't find a way to do that so it won't put a row between each task.  I tried using a list, but in the end, got the same problem--the group still forced it to behave that way.

I know I can insert a page break between groups, but that would be a huge waste of paper, having each employee on a separate sheet.

Is there a way to essentially have each employee (group), be in a separate "table"--such that I would have maybe a half dozen on a sheet that could easily be guillotined?

EDIT:  Here's a screenshot of it as it is now:

[Table](http://s33.photobucket.com/user/Holonet/media/Untitled.png.html?sort=3&o=0)

I don't know how I could use a rectangle because the results (groups) are all in the same table.  The idea would be to insert a space between each group (person).

Comment: Hi Holonet.. can you provide a screenshot of your table on report with grouping?

Comment: Have you tried using a rectangle? No matter what data you have in the rectangle, the height you set it to will always be the same... You could possibly set the rectangle height to add extra white space...